# Renaming Sheets from cells with a loop

Tags: excel, vba, cell

The code below is what i use to rename a bunch of sheets within a workbook. it works perfectly. It renames the sheet based off of a cell in that sheet. but now i have two sheets trying to use the same name. So i want to keep the same code but add a loop so if that happens, it will add a "2" to the second sheet. Ie cell contains "John Doe". Sheet will rename to "John Doe" and the next sheet that tries to use it will rename "John Doe 2"

Thank you

```
Sub RenameLaborLog()
    Dim rs As Worksheet
    For Each rs In Sheets
        rs.Name = Split(rs.Range("H4").Value, " ")(1) & ", " & Left(Split(rs.Range("H4").Value)(0), 1) & "."

    Next rs
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you keep a list with all the names generated until now ? and check that list first to see if the name was already generated ? if true, then add that _2, _3 ...

Comment: Check out the Answers [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068769/iferror-in-in-this-macro/34069903#34069903)  They show many different ways to check if a sheet exists.

Comment: Im not sure how to do that. My VB skills are entry level at best. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to show another way you can reach your goal

```
Sub RenameLaborLog()
  Dim rs As Worksheet, i As Long, str As String
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each rs In Sheets
    str = Split(rs.Range("H4").Value, " ")(1) & ", " & Left(Split(rs.Range("H4").Value)(0), 1) & "."
    rs.Name = str
    i = 1
    While Err.Number <> 0 And i < 20
      Err.Clear: i = i + 1
      rs.Name = str & i
    Wend
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox "Error: " & rs.Name & " cant be set to any " & str: Exit Sub
  Next rs
End Sub
```

it tries to set the name (and if that is not working it sets the name & 2 - 19 (if that doesnt work, it pops up a message box and exits the sub)

Answer (score 0):

Use a controlled error to adjust the string containing the worksheet name until it find something it can use.

```
Sub RenameLaborLog()
    Dim rs As Worksheet, snam As String, idupe As Long

    On Error GoTo bm_Dupe_WS_Name

    For Each rs In Sheets
        idupe = 1
        snam = Split(rs.Range("H4").Value, " ")(1) & ", " & _
               Left(Split(rs.Range("H4").Value)(0), 1) & "."
        rs.Name = snam
    Next rs

bm_Dupe_WS_Name:

    If idupe > 8 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & snam & " - " & Err.Description
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Right(snam, 1) = CStr(idupe) Then
        snam = Trim(Left(snam, Len(snam) - 1))
    End If
    idupe = idupe + 1
    snam = snam & Chr(32) & idupe
    Resume
End Sub
```

I have it set yo attempt a numerical suffix up to **9**. It it reaches that, it reports the error and exits the sub. I would not recommend running this without an escape clause. If nothing else, you may run into an illegal character when parsing the string for the worksheet name.

Answer (score 0):

Jeeped beat me to it, but here is another possible adjustment you could make:

```
Sub RenameLaborLog()

    Dim rs As Worksheet, wsName As String, wsCheck As Worksheet, i As Integer

    For Each rs In Sheets
        ' Get the sheet name
        wsName = Split(rs.Range("H4").Value, " ")(1) & ", " & Left(Split(rs.Range("H4").Value)(0), 1) & "."
        ' Check if it exists
        Set wsCheck = Nothing: On Error Resume Next: Set wsCheck = wsName: On Error GoTo 0
        ' Check if multiples already exist
        While Not wsCheck Is Nothing
            ' If even one exits, "i" will be iterated
            i = i + 1
            Set wsCheck = Nothing: On Error Resume Next: Set wsCheck = wsName & "_" & i: On Error GoTo 0
        Wend
        ' If at least one name already existed, name it with the current iteration.
        If Not i = 0 Then wsName = wsName & "_" & i
        rs.Name = wsName
    Next rs
    Set rs = Nothing: Set wsCheck = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link @Scott Craner provided in his comment, I am providing another solution that I believe is a bit more functional and cleaner and easier to read.

```
Sub RenameLaborLog()

    Dim rs As Worksheet, sName As String
    For Each rs In Sheets

        sName = Split(rs.Range("H4").Value, " ")(1) & ", " & Left(Split(rs.Range("H4").Value)(0), 1) & "."

        i = 1

        Do

            If Not WorksheetExist(sName) Then
                rs.Name = sName
                Exit Do
            Else: sName = sName & "_" & i + 1
            End If

        Loop

    Next rs

End Sub

Function WorksheetExist(sName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean

Dim wbCheck As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
If wb Is Nothing Then Set wbCheck = ThisWorkbook Else: Set wbCheck = wb

WorksheetExist = False

For Each ws In wbCheck.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = sName Then
        WorksheetExist = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

End Function
```